Data from API is getting stuck in between in my flutter application
I have created the splash screen, where I am calling API and storing the data into the SharedPreferences, and when data is completely fetched the screen is supposed to be navigated automatically to the next screen. Here is my code of splashScreen ===>
import 'package:dtcameo/provider/generalsettingprovider.dart';
import 'package:dtcameo/widget/mybottomnavigationbar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    api();
  }

  api() async {
    final provider =
        Provider.of<GeneralSettingProvider>(context, listen: false);
    provider.fetchGeneralSetting();

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (provider.fetchGeneralSetting() != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= provider.generalSettingModel!.result!.length; i++) {
        prefs.setString(provider.generalSettingModel!.result?[i].key ?? '',
            provider.generalSettingModel!.result?[i].value ?? '');
      }
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const BottomMenuBar()));
    }
  }

  getdata() async {
    final provider = Provider.of<GeneralSettingProvider>(context);

    if (provider.loading) {
      debugPrint("===> Loading...");
    } else {
      debugPrint("===> ${provider.generalSettingModel!.status}");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getdata();
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash-img.png')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

There are total 64 numbers of key-value pair in my model class, but the problem is when it comes to the 47 number it is getting stuck and the navigation is not happening
what should i do?
I have tried by modifying my provider class but nothing was happend currently my provider class is as below ==>
import 'package:dtcameo/model/generalsettingmodel.dart';
import 'package:dtcameo/services/apiservice.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class GeneralSettingProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  GeneralSettingModel? generalSettingModel;
  bool _loading = false;
  bool get loading => _loading;
  String? errorMessage;

  fetchGeneralSetting() async {
    _loading = true;
    generalSettingModel = await ApiService().generalSetting();
    _loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

the output in my debug console is as below ==>
 {
I/flutter (16204): ║                 id: 46,
I/flutter (16204): ║                 key: "fb_interstiatial_id",
I/flutter (16204): ║                 value: "",
I/flutter (16204): ║                 created_at: "2022-08-03T12:38:42.000000Z",
I/flutter (16204): ║                 updated_at: "2024-04-24T06:11:20.000000Z"
I/flutter (16204): ║            },
I/flutter (16204): ║            {
I/flutter (16204): ║                 id: 47,
I/flutter (16204): ║                 key: "fb_rewardvideo_status",
I/flutter (16204): ║                 value: "0",
I/flutter (16204): ║                 created_at: "2022-08-03T12:38:42.000000Z",

here is my fetchGeneralSetting() function code:
class GeneralSettingProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  GeneralSettingModel? generalSettingModel;
  bool _loading = false;
  bool get loading => _loading;
  String? errorMessage;

  fetchGeneralSetting() async {
    _loading = true;
    generalSettingModel = await ApiService().generalSetting();
    _loading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Additionally I am getting this line in my debug console ::
W/ratelimit( 9649): Single process limit 250/s drop 102 lines.


Check API in postman, if it gives proper response or any bracket is missing.

I have rechecked my API response in Insomnia, everything is perfect there.
thank you for showing concern.

Inside your api(). The provider.fetchGeneralSetting() is calling two times without waiting and I think the if condition
if (provider.fetchGeneralSetting() != null) {}

Should be like this:
if (provider.fetchGeneralSetting != null) 

Here's the revised version of your code. Try it.
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    api();
  }

  Future<void> api() async {
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final provider =
        Provider.of<GeneralSettingProvider>(context, listen: false);
    await provider.fetchGeneralSetting(); // Wait for this to complete

   
    if (provider.generalSettingModel != null &&
        provider.generalSettingModel!.result != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < provider.generalSettingModel!.result!.length; i++) {
        await prefs.setString(provider.generalSettingModel!.result![i].key ?? '',
            provider.generalSettingModel!.result![i].value ?? '');
      }
      // Navigate after all keys have been set
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const BottomMenuBar()));
    }
  }

  Future<void> getdata() async {
    final provider = Provider.of<GeneralSettingProvider>(context, listen: true);

    if (provider.loading) {
      debugPrint("===> Loading...");
    } else {
      debugPrint("===> ${provider.generalSettingModel?.status}");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getdata();
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash-img.png')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Thank you for your quick support, but unfortunately it did not worked for me.
Still keep supporting. Thank you

Still the UI is stuck??

yes sir still it stuck
cause there is total 62 key-value pair in the data from API, but in debug console it is coming till 47

I guess you are receiving wrong data after 47 check your data once. and add the fetchGeneralSetting() function code.

wait let me add fetchGeneralSetting() function code in the question

Inside your "ApiService().generalSetting()" try to print the response and check here if you are getting all 62 key-value pair data or not.

Sorry for late replying, but can you please elaborate with any example sir??

Inside your generalSetting() method just add print statement of the result you receiving from server.
